# difference between interaction with anova and contrast functions

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, interaction, contrasts

I'm trying to understand the difference between the interaction with the `anova` function and the interaction with the `contrast` function

```
library(emmeans)
pigs2 <- subset(pigs, pigs$percent<15)
pigs.lm <- lm(log(conc) ~ source*factor(percent), data = pigs2)
anova(pigs.lm)
```

This is the output for the interaction

```
                        Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F) 
source:factor(percent)  2 0.003116 0.001558  0.1211 0.887130
```

Now using `emmeans`

```
emm <- emmeans(pigs.lm, ~ source * factor(percent))
contrast(emm, list(con = c(1,0,-1,-1,0,1)))
```

which gives me

```
     contrast    estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
    con      -0.01946701 0.1389334 11   -0.14  0.8911
```

I realize that the significance is very similar, but shouldn't they be exactly the same? Also shouldn't the `F value` in the `anova` output above be the same as the `t.ratio` squared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will note in the anova table that the interaction has 2 d.f. That means that the interaction comprises *two* dimensions, and you need to see *two* interaction contrasts to explain it all. Try this:

```
(cons = contrast(emm, interaction = "consec"))
```

That shows one example of two contrasts involved in the interaction, and tests for each one. Do:

```
coef(cons)
```

to see exactly the contrast coefficients.

Finally, do

```
test(cons, joint = TRUE)
```

to see a test of the two contrasts jointly.